# Why does QDialogButtonBox labels' language change between design and execution?

Tags: c++, qt5, qt-creator, qlocale

I use a french version of QtCreator v4.11.1
When I create a default QDialogButtonBox using the form designer
(or using Qt Designer), the buttons are labelled in french language.
Both buttons have 'OK' and 'Annuler' labels as seen below.

[image]

However, when I execute the application, the labels are changed into
english language and are labelled 'OK' and 'Cancel' as show below.

[image]

I tried to search but could not find ways to keep the labels as they are
designed (which means in french). Even after setting the QLocale explicitly
with code, the labels are always in English when the application is executed.

Is it an issue with QT or am I missing some steps?
How can I keep the labels in french language when compiled?

Comment: Are you loading the translators ?

Comment: At least not explicitly because I only use what is generated by QtCreator by default

Comment: I think you meant 'Qt Designer', try loading the translators explicitly, I really don't use/like designer.

Comment: Could you show me some example of code to activate translators? I have trie to set QLocale but no effect.

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtranslator.html